# unity game can not be simulated on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator

I was trying to run my unity game on iPhone 4s simulator using Xcode to produce some screen shots for iTunes connect.

There are several problems I encountered on the way and tons of confusion hoping someone might shine some light here.

I have tried all other simulators (iPads, iPhones) and never had any problems.

When I select simulator SDK in the player setting i notice that "architecture" field is greyed out and changed from "Universal" to "x86_64"

When I open Xcode I can't select iPhone 4s as a simulator to run this build on. In order to be able to I have to go to "Build settings" -> "Architectures" -> "Architectures" and change from "x86_64" to "Standard architectures i386 x86_64". After this change iPhone 4s it is now available as a simulator choice.

Xcode builds without errors but as soon as I start the app on the simulator it fails, it won't even get to unity logo.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN14Il2CppIUnknown3IIDE Referenced from:
/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFABF00E-A414-495A-8FF6-
8AF50B97343C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FB0C2EB1-3581-4061-BBC5-
98F09F395218/myapp.app/myapp Expected in: flat namespace in 
/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFABF00E-A414-495A-8FF6-
8AF50B97343C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FB0C2EB1-3581-4061-BBC5-
98F09F395218/myapp.app/myapp
```

I have reproduced this exact same error with an empty unity app.

Here are the questions I hope you could answer:

1. Is this the proper way to simulate iPhone 4s?  If not how should I go about it?
2. Is there some problem a novice developer doesn't know regarding those different architectures?
3. Considering that when "Device SDK" is chosen in player setting, architecture is "Universal" (in unity editor) can I expect this app to work on the actual device?

The versions in use are **Unity 5.3.4f1** and **Xcode 7.2**.

Comment: Thanks for editing, i have looked all over the place and tried different setting looked at stuff like: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1090904/project-built-for-ios-simulation-but-no-simulators.html and http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios-xcode-simulator-problem.364532/ but i keep getting the same error. Could someone confirm that he can create build and simulate an empty unity project on iphone 4s ?

Comment: Change the Target SDK to Simulator SDK. Do this from Unity **Edit->Build Settings select iOS->Player Settings** then **Change Target SDK** to **Simulator SDK**.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware of that setting, i have been succesfully using other simulators ( both iphone and ipads). The problem is iphone 4s the only simulator available that i could take 3.5 inch screenshots in.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment....You mean if you do what I just said, it won't be able to simulate iphone 4s?

Comment: Yes correct. So basicly in untiy editor i go to the place you specified, change "Target SDK" to "Simulator SDK" from "Device SDK". Project builds, I open it in Xcode. Now there are several simulators available (iPad air, ipad air2, ipad pro, iphone from 5s to 6s plus) but not iphone 4s. To make it available i have to fiddle with settings in xcode as specified in the post. Yet no matter what i try i always get the same error.

Comment: Ok. I see your problem. What is the simulator version installed in your xcode?

Comment: Thank you for your time @Programmer. Simulator ver is 9.2 (SimulatorApp-643 CoreSimulator-201.3)

Comment: I don't see the problem here. The only thing left is to download **Xcode-7.3** then download the latest **Unity 5.4.0B15** http://unity3d.com/unity/beta. Backup your project just in-case. Let me know if that solved your problem. Maybe that was a problem that is fixed in both latest xcode and unity.

Comment: minor formatting improvements

Answer (score 3):

Go to Player Settings, under Other Settings then under Configuration **choose** **Mono2x for Scripting Backend**.

[image]